# The format of time/duration in MPEG-DASH .MPD file?

Tags: datetime, video-streaming

The following is a snap of a .mpd file:

```
<MPD type="static" xmlns="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:full:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.5S" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H1M59.89S">
 <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.sourceforge.net">
  <Title>Media Presentation Description for file hdworld_0696kbps_ffmpeg_track1.mp4 generated with GPAC </Title>
 </ProgramInformation>
 <Period start="PT0S" duration="PT0H1M59.89S">
```

For attributes of time-range type, like *minBufferTime*, *mediaPresentationDuration*, *start* or *duration*, they seems to share the same format. Does anyone know what format it is and where I can get a spec for that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The format is [ISO8601 duration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

Comment: thank you :) I don't understand why it is not in the spec.

Answer (score 5):

Don't know a spec for that, also didn't find it in the standard, but from what i gathered so far, the format is pretty simple:

You always have 'PT' as a prefix, then you give a time-range in units of seconds (S), minutes (M), hours (H) and days (D). For seconds, fractional values are possible.

**Back to the manifest snap you posted**:

`mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H1M59.89S"` refers to a mediaPresentationDuration of 0 hours, 1 minute and 59.89 seconds.

`minBufferTime="PT1.5S"` refers to a minBufferTime 1.5 seconds.

`start="PT0S"` means start is "at" 0 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for information, but I am still looking for a spec for this ;)

Comment: The assumption that they always start with `PT` as a prefix is incorrect. As the accepted answer states, these values follow the ISO 8601 Duration spec.

This means that if the value includes "period" components, such as years, months, weeks, or days, the P and T will not be adjacent.